# .git/info/exclude not ignoring files

Tags: git

I added a `Web.config` file to my `.git/info/exclude`. I ran `git update-index --assume-unchanged path/to/Web.config`. I also tried running `git update-index --skip-worktree path/to/Web.config`. Despite this, when I run `git ls-files -v . | grep ^S` (which I understand is supposed to list the assume-unchanged files) I do not see the `Web.config` listed.

Changes to the `Web.config` do not show up in `git status`, but when I try to change branches after changing the `Web.config`, I get "Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:"

For my purposes I do not want to use a `.gitignore` and I do not want to  `git rm --cached` the `Web.config`, because both require that I commit these changes. This is not an option in my situation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The TL;DR answer is that neither `.git/info/exclude` nor `.gitignore` have any effect on a tracked file.  Using `git update-index --skip-worktree` (or `--assume-unchanged`) just make Git stop comparing the index version to the work-tree version.  The file is still tracked and still goes into every new commit.  This means that trying to move from a newer commit to an older one may try to change the content of the file in your work-tree.  There is no workaround for this (other than moving the content out of the way so that Git can freely overwrite the file that's not there for the moment).

#### You must remove the file (from the index)

For a file to be *tracked* in Git, it must be in the index.  That is, the index—the mysterious object that Git uses to build the *next* commit—has a copy of a file with some path name *P*.

If path *P* is in the index, no amount of fiddling with ignore files will make *P* **stop** being in the index.  The **only** way to make *P* stop being in the index is to change the contents of the index.

There are several ways to change the contents of the index.  Since the index is *what will be in the next commit*, you can:

- Check out a commit that does not have a file whose path name is *P*.

  This removes path *P* from the index, **and removes the file whose path is *P* from the work-tree as well.**  Git will object to the `git checkout` if the contents of path *P* do not match the contents stored in the current (HEAD) commit, telling you that you will lose these changes (which is true, you *will* lose these changes; though you can of course move the file out of the way first, then move it back later).

  Of course, as soon as you check out another commit that *does* have path *P* in it, the file will re-appear in the index and in your work-tree, with the content as stored in that other commit.  As before, Git will object to the `git checkout` if it will overwrite data.
- Use `git rm` to *remove* the file.  Using `git rm --cached` will remove *P* from the index without disturbing the file in your work-tree.

  You can now make a new commit that does not have a file whose path name is *P*.

  This allows you to use the other method: you now have a commit that does not have path *P* in it, so any time you want to get to an index that does not have path *P* in it, this new commit you just made is a suitable commit for `git checkout`.

That's the only way to make the path become untracked: you **must** remove it, either by a `git checkout` of a commit that lacks the path, or by an explicit remove step.  *There are no other ways to make the file become untracked.*  Note as well that the "untracked-ness" of the file *continues to depend* on the index contents, which change whenever you `git checkout` commits that have, or lack, *P*.

#### The alternative is setting the tricky index bits

If you are willing to live with a file that *is* tracked, but rarely has any attention paid to it, you can leave path *P* in the index, but set the *skip-worktree* bit (or the *assume-unchanged* bit, though it has a different purpose, and the *skip-worktree* bit is the one you should usually use).

Setting this bit tells Git not to compare the index version of *P* with the work-tree version of *P*.  This means that Git will, in general, not report that *P* needs to be staged with `git add`.  It will sometimes *seem* like *P* is not even tracked.  However, since some file content *is* being tracked under path *P*, every new commit made while in this state will continue to have the (old) content for path *P*.  This affects you when you do finally remove *P* from the index, in that later `git checkout` operations on these commits behave as described above, putting *P* back into the index.